# Internet Explorer drops Referer header when fetching a PDF in chunks

Tags: internet-explorer-11, http-referer

We have a web app that serves PDFs. We see **occasional failures** for Internet Explorer 11 only. The failure is connected to app logic which is relying on the *Referer* header. (I know, using the *Referer* header is not robust.)

The problem occurs when IE tries to **fetch a large PDF in chunks**. The first chunk is returned OK, and its HTTP request has a *Referer* header.

The second chunk is not OK. For the second chunk, the *Referer* header is absent from the HTTP request. This initiates app logic which depends on an absent *Referer* header, and the download of the PDF fails as a side effect.

Why is the *Referer* header dropped in the middle of the fetch, and is there anything I can do about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We got around the problem by altering the *Accept-Ranges* header in server HTTP Responses.

For URLs that end in *.pdf*, we changed the header to:

```
Accept-Ranges: none
```

This ensures the client doesn't fetch the file in chunks.